# How to set a parameter in MS Test Manager 2010 to open a web browser

Tags: test-management, mstest, mtm

I have recently started using Microsoft Test Manager 2010 and watched a few videos on the features for it. In one of the videos there was a shared step that when you run the test manually it opened IE. I would like to know how it is possible to create this shared step and any other useful features like that.

The reason I would like to know is that I don't want to have to continually write steps to open the web application that I am testing and would like to have the home page displayed automatically at the start of each test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have figured out how to accomplish this and I will post it here since there has been a lot of views of the question but no answer.

In test manager, select the Organize tab. Then select the Shared Steps Manager. Create a shared step and pace a parameter in it, e.g. '@Location', enter the URL you wish to navigate to in the parameter at the bottom of the form, and save & close.

Select the shared step in Shared Steps Manager and click the Create Action Recording. Now follow the steps and nav to the URL you require and save. Add the shared step to your test — you will need to add the URL into the @Location parameter that is now displayed in the test you are creating.